# Activiti Workflow Engine: Deployment Not Successful

Tags: xml, deployment, workflow, activiti

currently I am working with activity workflow engine and XML to develop business process diagram. FYI, the activiti workflow diagram is running above Tomcat server.

But i don't know why, I always fail to deploy my process. Here is my XML code:

```
<definitions id="definitions"
  targetNamespace="http://activiti.org/bpmn20" 
  xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
  xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">

        <process id="accidentForm" name="accidentFormProcess">

          <startEvent id="startEvent" />

          <sequenceFlow id='flow1' sourceRef='startEvent' targetRef='submitForm' />

          <userTask id="submitForm" name="Submit Accident Form" >
            <documentation>
             Submit Accident Form
            </documentation>
            <potentialOwner>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>employee</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </potentialOwner>
          </userTask>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow2' sourceRef='submitForm' targetRef='parallelTask' />

          <intermediateCatchEvent id="parallelTask" >
            <messageEventDefinition messageRef="submission" />
          </intermediateCatchEvent>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow3' sourceRef='parallelTask' targetRef='sendBoss' />

          <userTask id="sendBoss" name="Send Email Notification to Boss or Sacharbeiter" >
            <documentation>
             Send Email Notification to Boss or Sacharbeiter
            </documentation>
            <potentialOwner>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>smtp</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </potentialOwner>
          </userTask>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow4' sourceRef='parallelTask' targetRef='sendEmployee' />

          <userTask id="sendBoss" name="Send Email Confirmation to Employee" >
            <documentation>
             Send Email Confirmation to Employee
            </documentation>
            <potentialOwner>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>smtp</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </potentialOwner>
          </userTask>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow5' sourceRef='sendBoss' targetRef='parallelTask2' />

          <intermediateCatchEvent id="parallelTask2" >
            <messageEventDefinition messageRef="submission" />
          </intermediateCatchEvent>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow6' sourceRef='sendEmployee' targetRef='parallelTask2' />

          <sequenceFlow id='flow7' sourceRef='parallelTask2' targetRef='reviewForm' />

          <userTask id="bossSign" name="Form Reviewed and Signed By The Boss or Sacharbeiter" >
            <documentation>
             Form Reviewed and Signed By The Boss or Sacharbeiter
            </documentation>
            <potentialOwner>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>boss</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </potentialOwner>
          </userTask>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow8' sourceRef='reviewForm' targetRef='sendFormBO' />

          <userTask id="sendFormBO" name="Boss or Sacharbeiter Submit Signed Form to The System" >
            <documentation>
             Boss or Sacharbeiter Submit Signed Form to The System
            </documentation>
            <potentialOwner>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>boss</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </potentialOwner>
          </userTask>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow9' sourceRef='sendFormBO' targetRef='sendEmailBO' />

          <userTask id="sendEmailBO" name="Send Email Notification to Back Office" >
            <documentation>
             Send Email Notification to Back Office
            </documentation>
            <potentialOwner>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>smtp</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </potentialOwner>
          </userTask>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow10' sourceRef='sendEmailBO' targetRef='claimAccident' />

          <userTask id="claimAccident" name="Back Office Claim Accident to Insurance Company" >
            <documentation>
             Back Office Claim Accident to Insurance Company
            </documentation>
            <potentialOwner>
              <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                <formalExpression>backoffice</formalExpression>
              </resourceAssignmentExpression>
            </potentialOwner>
          </userTask>

          <sequenceFlow id='flow11' sourceRef='claimAccident' targetRef='endProcess' />

          <endEvent id="endProcess" />

         </process>
</definitions>
```

Is there anything wrong with my XML? And is there any way to do debugging. For example by using some log or error console? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly there are multiple userTask with ID value 'sendBoss'. Probably to be called 'sendEmploye'.
- There is no ID/IDREF binding for IDREF 'reviewForm' in sequence flow 'flow7'.
- There is no message definition referenced in intermediate event 'parallelTask'.

TIP: 
You can use activiti designer plugin for eclipse. http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Fwf-install-activiti-designer.html

Configure logger in activiti. http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#loggingConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is to use Activiti Designer Plug-ins in Eclipse.
Make use of Maven for activiti dependency.
Must try it works. And, for deployment use of "**Repository Service**" is Must.
It is one of the API services provided by the process Engine of Activiti.